# Docker registry --insecure-registry not working

Tags: ssl, docker, https

I'm trying to run Docker registry for internal use, on CentOS 7.

I've set up the Docker config from `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` as follows:

```
[Service]
.... 
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --insecure-registry 127.0.0.1:5000
....
```

And then started the docker daemon with `systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo service docker start`, and confirmed that docker was running with the option with `ps -ef | grep docker`:

```
root     116221      1  0 13:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --insecure-registry 127.0.0.1:5000
```

But when I tried to connect to the registry with `https`, it failed.

```
# Try from the server which the registry is running

curl -X GET https://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/_ping
=> curl: (35) Encountered end of file


# Try from the remote client

curl -X GET https://{registry-server-ip}:5000/v1/_ping
=> curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

Of course I've succeed to access the registry with `http`:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/_ping
=> {"host": ["Linux", ...}
```

For reference,

```
# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:23:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:23:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

What should I have to check more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can access in http but not in https, is simply because you configured your registry as an insecure-registry. Which means, no TLS enabled. You can find more information about secured registry at [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#/restricting-access) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#/auth).

If you want to make https also works, you need to prepare a CA, and config your registry with it. Please make sure your CA is configured properly.

EDIT:
I guess you might misunderstanding what "insecure-registry" is. This feature doesn't enable really TLS support, it let you creating a private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate. If you want HTTPS works, you have two choices: use a self-signed CA or buy a CA. The [troubleshoot part here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#/troubleshooting-insecure-registry) may help you.

EDIT2: To give HTTP access a try, I run a simple test following the guide on registry's official image page: [Run the registry docker container: Quick version](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/)

Here is the steps:

1. Add insecure option `DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=127.0.0.1:5000"`,
   then restart docker service.
2. `$ docker run -p 5000:5000 -v /home/mypc/data:/tmp/registry-dev registry`
3. `$ docker tag hello-world 127.0.0.1:5000/hello`
4. `$ docker push 127.0.0.1:5000/hello`

The output is:

> ```
> The push refers to a repository [127.0.0.1:5000/hello]
>
> a02596fdd012: Image successfully pushed 
>
> Pushing tag for rev [c54a2cc56cbb] on {http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/repositories/hello/tags/latest}
> ```

The docker push was working.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! I had thought that `--insecure-registry` option is to allow remote access such as `docker pull` or `docker push` without CA. 

But what I understand by your comment is that I need to configure CA without `--insecure-registry` to allow `docker pull` or `docker push` as the commands use `https`, am I right?

Comment: @Seonho Hi, yes, --insecure-registry allows you to do remote access without CA, but in this case, the remote access is HTTP only. You can do HTTPS, as long as you have a CA. But two cases depends on what kind of CA you have: 1. If your CA is self-signed(means it is not published by a trusted signer), then you have to add --insecure-registry option. 2. If your CA is trusted(for example you bought one), then you don't need this --insecure-registry option. Hope this helpful.

Comment: @Seonho Last thing I have to mention is that you can use Self-signed CA, and without --insecure-registry option. Check the steps here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#/using-self-signed-certificates In step 4, "Instruct every docker daemon to trust your self-signed certificate".

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. In summary finally, as I understand, 1. `--insecure-registry` is followed by the type of CA (self-signed or trusted-signed) I have, but not about the necessity of CA. 2. That is, I have to configure CA anyway to use `pull` or `push` images to the registry because the commands are executed through HTTPS.

Comment: @Seonho 1. Correct. 2. No, pull and push also works on plain HTTP, you can set up a registry without CA, but with --insecure-registry option enabled. Docker pull and push should also works.

Comment: Ah.. does that mean I can pull and push my images through HTTP, without CA? This was what I want to set up of, but when I try to push my image from the client then it's accessing through HTTPS. Are there any other configurations with which HTTP to be used?

Comment: @Seonho I'm not sure how you config your registry, so I give a quick start guide above, please see above answer. You may need to check your config carefully to make sure all the configure correct.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not being to respond for your answer as I was in my holidays . I've tried following your guide and succeed! :) But the problem is, I could get success with 127.0.0.1 and found it's using HTTP, but it's using HTTPS when I try to use the public IP address :( Is there any other concerns for this situation?

Comment: @Seonho Sorry I can't give you more suggestion unless you share the config of your registry. Just two things to check: make sure you added your public IP to insecure-registry, and make sure the service on that public IP does not enable TLS.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this link as well :

> https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/

It explains you where to store certificates on the docker client machines for the registry to be no more considered as an insecure one.

Comment: Then you have to create the certificates for your private registry. Then you have to copy manually the ca into each docker client instances which would like to access under /etc/docker/certs.d/hostname:port and then you will be able to push your images.